# NodeJS/Firebase Cloud Functions - Generate Percentage Fee

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing Stripe into my app, however, I want to generate the fee amount via server side as this can allow me to update as and when. I've tried to have a go, but to no luck.

```
exports.calculateFees = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var total = req.body
  var percentageFeeCharge = 10
  var feeAmount = 0
    feeAmount = ((percentageFeeCharge/ 100) * total))
    return res.send(feeAmount)
  });
```

I can pass in the total from my app to the function which is cool, however, I need the amount to be generate with no decimals or symbols as Stripe deals with pennies i.e. £1.00 would equate to 100 etc.

I believe the `res()` is the response which is what I need to get the amount back, I believe so? I'm new to NodeJS so this may be simple, but I am struggling.

Comment: Yes, `res` is the response. Are you experiencing any particular issues? If yes, please specify so in your question.

Comment: @DenisT. I managed to figure it out, I needed to use .fixed(2) I believe? It's working now none the less. I appreciate your response!